# cloud-init not working in ubuntu with a iso attached

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, cloud-init

I'm generating ubuntu image in Windows for Hyper-V. The main objective is to add through cloud-init some customizations in order to modify them on boot with custom meta-data and user-data files.

Using ubuntu 20.04 and cloud-init 20.4.1

The meta-data and user-data files are valid and simple, just adding hostname to be specific.

I create de metadata iso with the following command.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assesment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg\oscdimg.exe "$($pathtofiles)" $metadataiso -j2 -lcidata`

So, I'm generating an iso ($metadataiso path and file name)containing the files in $pathtofiles (meta-data and user-data files) and labelling it as cidata.

When I startup the instance in Hyper-V iso is attached into the VM but it's not mounted neither cloud-init is executed and I'm being lost because all examples seem quite simple and straightforward.

Can someone give me some support on how to automatically execute the cidata iso to consider meta-data and user-data files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. Also mounting an ISO to a VM created in Microsoft Hyper-V.

Generating the ISO exactly as described in the [cloud-init NoCloud data source documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html).

Install image was `ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64`.

Order of Operations:

1. Install OS *without* cidata ISO inserted.
2. Reboot VM *without* cidata ISO inserted.
3. Power off VM, insert cidata ISO, power on VM.

In addition to what the OP as posted, here are some additional debugging outputs. These are captured from within the VM, after step #3.

*Virtual DVD is visible to OS, has correct file system and label.*

```
$ lsblk -f
NAME                      FSTYPE      LABEL  UUID
sr0                       iso9660     cidata 2021-09-23-16-00-18-00
```

*If mounted, virtual DVD shows correct file contents*

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt
mount: /mnt: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
$ ls /mnt
meta-data  user-data
```

*The `ISO9660_DEVS=/dev/sr0=cidata` entry in the log looks right, but seems to be overridden by a preset `datasource_list: [None]`*

```
$ cat /run/cloud-init/ds-identify.log
/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg set datasource_list: [None]
FS_LABELS=cidata
ISO9660_DEVS=/dev/sr0=cidata
```

*It appears that `DataSourceNone` was the only data source used*

```
$ cat /run/cloud-init/result.json
{
 "v1": {
  "datasource": "DataSourceNone",
  "errors": []
 }
}
```

**Update**: Seems related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1940791